# How sort generic list like datatable in c#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, datatable

i working on c# project(winform).

on my project, i sorted a datatable like this:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "a ASC, b ASC, c ASC";
```

now with below expression, i sorted a generic list, but results is different against datatale results.

```
var newList = oldList.OrderBy(x => x.a).OrderBy(x => x.b).OrderBy(x => x.c).ToList();
```

how can sorted my generic list like datatable results?
(i want have same sort datatable results in generic list)

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)/[`ThenByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) after first [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)/[`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) operator - it performs subsequent ordering of already ordered sequence:

```
var newList = oldList.OrderBy(x => x.a)
                     .ThenBy(x => x.b)
                     .ThenBy(x => x.c)
                     .ToList();
```

Otherwise you are re-ordering full sequence each time by different value (i.e. you are introducing new primary ordering that ignores previous ordering - see *Remarks* section on MSDN). And you'll end up with sequence sorted only by value provided to last `OrderBy` call (property `c` in your case). Your current code is equivalent of

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "a ASC";
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "b ASC";
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "c ASC";
```